# error with discord.py NoneType object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Ok, so I try to make a command with on_message, I put `await bot.process_commands(message)`. But it always raises the `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`.

```py
import os
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
activity = discord.Activity(name='null, dying, trying to fix me', type=discord.ActivityType.watching)

client = discord.Client(intents=intents, activity = activity)
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents,command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    channel = client.get_channel(956302622170701946)
    await channel.send(f'connected successfully as {client.user.name}#{client.user.discriminator}')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('hello'):
        await message.channel.send("hello stopid")
    elif message.content.startswith('die'):
        await message.channel.send('ok :sob: i ded now')
        await client.close()

@bot.command
async def a(ctx):
    await ctx.send("a")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

this is the entire error:

```
2022-12-08 18:15:54 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\DBot\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\DBot\discordbot.py", line 25, in on_message
    await bot.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\DBot\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1389, in process_commands
    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\source\repos\DBot\DiscordBot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1285, in get_context
    if origin.author.id == self.user.id:  # type: ignore
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

i just want a command with the prefix '$' and sends back the args sent by the user

i probably did something stupid but still thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You only need the `bot` instance, client is unnecessary. CommandsBot is just upgraded discord.Client and also includes the @bot.event decorator
2. remove client.close() and move bot.process_commands(message) to the bottom of your on_message function

*Note you should not be doing anything else than prints in on_ready since that fires multiple times